# dumpe2fs: Block bitmap checksum does not match bitmap while trying to read '/dev/sda4' bitmaps

Tags: fsck, 19.04

Hey I had an issue with my pc just a few moments ago , but I was able to fix with after performing a repair on the dpkg packages as well as an Unmount -l and rebooting my pc .
After that I was able to access the desktop , I ran dumpe2fs to see if there is a problem with my filesystem .

I got the following warning :

```
dumpe2fs: Block bitmap checksum does not match bitmap while trying to read   '/dev/sda4' bitmaps
*** Run e2fsck now!
```

I ran e2fsck after that but I got this message :

```
e2fsck 1.44.6 (5-Mar-2019)
/dev/sda4 is mounted.



 WARNING!!! The filesystem is mounted. If you continue you ***WILL***
 cause ***SEVERE*** filesystem damage.


Do you really want to continue<n>? no
```

What should I do please ?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still need.
Follow step below.

1. reboot your computer
2. later show grub menu, choose advance options
3. choose kernel with recovery mode options
4. after show recovery menu, choose fsck
5. run command `fsck {your disk}`